# Align textviews in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: here]

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNameContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.29"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/fullname"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDiagnosisContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.57"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/diagnosis"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

**custom_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/diagnosis"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.57"
    android:text="@string/diagnosis"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastffupcontainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lastffup"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastffup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lastffup"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

This is the result:
   [image]

But I can't seem to make those spaces between the textviews. Any ideas?

Comment: Add image you are getting with the above xmls

Comment: @Manishika I added it for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like the only issue you are having is having the "Diagnosis" `TextView` in the `ListView` spaced more to the right. For this I would change that `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`. Then you can give it the property `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and add in some `android:marginRight="some dp"` if needed.

Comment: Question, what because I want it to scale accordingly to multiple screen sizes, if I set the marginRight to some dp, would it not scale?

Comment: It will depend on screen density I believe. If that doesn't work you might try changing your `weights` to something like 1,1,2

Comment: Tried it but it's still not making spaces?

Comment: If its taking up the space you want it to then you can use empty `Views` with `<View>` and give it a height, width, and weight if you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android's new fancy GridLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) to get exactly what you're looking for.

Try and replace your LinearLayout tags with GridLayout instead and it just might work for you. (make sure you add the support library to your project if you need to support devices < api 14).